# BitmapFont class does not have getBound(String) method

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Previously I used *getBound* method for **BitmapFont** class in **libgdx**, but now, I am unable to use it.

I cannot find the changes in latest version.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `API 1.5.6` we have a different way to get the String bound. try this

```
GlyphLayout layout = new GlyphLayout();
layout.setText(bitmapFont,"text");
float width = layout.width;
float height = layout.height;
```

and it's not recommended to create new `GlyphLayout` on each frame, create once and use it.

Comment: setText doesn't take string as parameter? :-(

Comment: And how do I use that with __fontObject.draw__ method?

Comment: it's `setText(BitmapFont, CharSequence)`